# Vaadin 14.10.1 error in flow-server 2.9.2 with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jsoup.nodes.Element.traverse(org.jsoup.select.NodeVisitor)

Tags: jsoup, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I have recently updated the vaadin version from 14.4.4 to 14.10.1 due to https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/16905 and now i am facing a new issue in flow-server 2.9.2 in class at line number 244 com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.TemplateDataAnalyzer.inspectTwoWayBindings(org.jsoup.nodes.Element element).

The exception i am getting  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.jsoup.nodes.Element org.jsoup.nodes.Element.traverse(org.jsoup.select.NodeVisitor)

I debugeed the code and found out that issue happens at the code as described in the question. But now, I am running out of ideas to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if you have the JSoup dependency pinned to an older version, or some other dependency that defines an incompatible version. You can use the `mvn dependency:tree` command to find out which version is used and how it is included.

Vaadin 14.10.1 is tested with version 1.15.3 of JSoup.

Comment: Thank you @Leif Åstrand for the quick hint, it solves the problem for me.